# TCP socket recv timeout in solaris after running correctly for few days [8 - 15 days] Why?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp, network-programming

We have implemented an SFTP client application in C, Solaris platform.
The application works fine for a few days, after that, socket operation [recv] fail
with timeout, we set timeout of 120 seconds [2 minute].

After a restart the process, everything works fine.

I want to know is :

1. How to check what is root cause for TCP error? `errno` is coming as 150 / some time timeout error
2. Where to get the reason for TCP error from system log file? in Solaris machine
3. Please provide some suggestion so I can find the root cause for this issue.

Comment: Did this just happen once?  Generally there can be glitches that cause you to use connectivity.  If you detect the loss of connectivity in your app and try to re-establish the connection, you can avoid restarting the process.  You may have to try several times until the OS frees up the port again.

Comment: when we try to reesablish connection , all connection to that server fails, if we try to restart process again start working fine

Comment: `netstat(1)` on the server side is your friend. It could be that the server is running out of file descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see this on Solaris `errno 150` referrs to `EINPROGRESS`, which might be set by the `connect()` call.

I'm not sure if `recv()` might set errno to `EINPROGRESS`, at least it does not on Linux. So you might be on the wrong trail when looking at the `recv()`.

Anyhow having errno set to `EINPROGRESS` by `connect()` does not necessarily indicate an error, but a somehow abnormal behavior of the process of connection in terms of being slower as expected.

See the `connect()` man page for details on how to handle such situations.

As the Linux man page for connect() does tells us much more than the Solaris one I herewith quote the first:

> EINPROGRESS The socket is nonblocking and the connection cannot be completed immediately.  It is possible to select(2) or poll(2) for completion by selecting the socket for writing. After select(2) indicates writability, use getsockopt(2) to read the SO_ERROR option at level SOL_SOCKET to determine whether connect() completed successfully (SO_ERROR is zero) or unsuccessfully (SO_ERROR is one of the usual error codes listed here, explaining the reason for the failure).

Comment: Yes- U r right , I got errno 150 when connecting with other serevr.

Comment: recv  timeout happen with another server , Is this means network has any issue ? when recv time out , I will try to connect again to same server but that conenct fails. [here i don't have the errno]

Answer (score 0):

Do you control the server side too? Is the server up all the time? Do you possibly interact with 2 or more servers? If yes to the last, your ARP cache might have dated entries that no longer correspond to the working server. If you control the servers, have them send gratuitous ARP requests upon booting. I don't know how exactly this is done for solaris, but this sounds like an ARP issue which you could monitor with, say, tcpdump.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Yes, Client conencts to multiple serevr. How to get the tcpdump in solaris ? Now already this issue happen , we have to wait for some more days to happen this issue again ? can we now able to get the old tcpdump,if yes how ?

Comment: By default Solaris has `snoop(1)` instead of `tcpdump`, see http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~arik/usail/man/solaris/snoop.1.html